# How do use Google Actions client library version 2 to create a dynamic list using forEach or any other iterator in Node

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am building using Node Google Actions client library version 2 to create a dynamic list using forEach or any other iterator in Node. Before I plough on does addList work with version 2 and if so does anyone have an example.

Hope someone can help but if not will do it myself and post up.

ditto for Carousel BTW but that should be very similar

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
let items = {};
let array = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
array.forEach(element => {
items[element] = {
    title: element,
    image: new Image({
           url: "url",
           alt: "alt image title"
           })
    )}
})
conv.ask("List")
conv.ask(new List({
   title: 'List',
   items: items
)};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's what I've got for just title and description. The image constructor function being nested in V2 now though is causing me grief.

Comment: I have edited the answer, don't forget to import Image from actions-on-google.

Comment: Mine isn't working. Must be my stupid coding. Thanks for the answer. Sometimes you need to be reminded by someone else to check again. I'll put it down as answered as soon as I look at it again and sorted out the selected item response. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help. If you want, share your code, maybe we can figure out what's wrong. The selected item is tricky. I solved it by saving the options presented and listing through them when I got the answer. In some scenarios, you can create an entity.